# jQuery .css not recommended in 'production' code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The jQuery [documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/css-styling-dimensions/) makes a remark, '
It's not recommended to use .css() as a setter in production-ready code, but when passing in an object to set CSS, CSS properties will be camelCased instead of using a hyphen.'

a) Why is it not recommended to use this in production-ready code?

b) "but when passing in an object to set CSS, CSS properties will be camelCased instead of using a hyphen."

So jQuery will modify "font-family" to "fontFamily" internally, or is this just a suggestion made here?

Are there any experienced programmers that can further clarify this?

Comment: I guess the recommended way is to toggle classes on and off and style in CSS. You can use both camelCase and hyphen-case in strings and camelCase in objects.

Comment: biggest issue with modifying inline style is it's a lot more work to undo than simply toggling classes...and therfore code is more to maintain. That comment is most likely intended to steer people toward best practices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer to point `a` is found on the same page you linked to:

> Using CSS Classes for Styling
>
> As a getter, the .css() method is valuable. However, it should
>   generally be avoided as a setter in production-ready code, because
>   it's generally best to keep presentational information out of
>   JavaScript code. Instead, write CSS rules for classes that describe
>   the various visual states, and then change the class on the element.